# Use variable of a constructor

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I am not a C++ expert hence I will try to make this as clear as possible, do not hesitate to ask me about any detail you would need.

I am using a program to handle ply file.
I am writing my code in `MyFunction.cpp`, and calling a function from AnotherFunction.cpp on my file like this : `MeshFunction(myplyfile)` (`MeshFunction` definition is in the file `AnotherFunction.cpp`).

Let's say that `MeshFunction` is using a vector of elements at a certain point and that I would like to get it in order to use it back in `MyFunction.cpp`; how is that possible ?

Thank you very much!

Yours faithfully,
L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update the interface of `MeshFunction` to accept `std::vector<Element>& elements` as another arugment.
2. Make sure to fill `elements` with the necessary data in the implementation of `MeshFunction`.
3. Supply the argument when calling the function.